# -[CFString length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3881940 when i scroll to near the bottom of a table on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

I have a problem debugging an iphone app that I am attempting to write and it got me stumped.

The app gets an XML doc from the a web site, parses it into an array, and then displays it in a table view. I have the parser in a separate file. The ViewDidLoad in RootViewController sends it a url, the parser goes to work and then returns an NSMutableArray.

When I run the app, it works fine with small XML files (5 entries or so, and 1-3 sections), but when i use a larger one(20+ rows, over 12 sections) i get the error "-[CFString length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3881940" when I scroll near the bottom of the tableview, just as the last section title is about to come onto the viewable area on the screen to be precise.

If I return a static string instead of the object in my array in this method it doesn't crash, but I can use NSLog to call the array and it returns the title no problems.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)indexPath {
    return [[returnedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath ] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

The returnedEvents array isn't released until -(void) dealloc {}

I have read a few other posts on here, and a few guides on debugging and as of yet am unable to find anything that was able to help me, I had be more than happy to post some code up here and any more information, I am just not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to have a go at helping me out.

** Update

Here is the Cell View Code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    
// Configure the cell.
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[[[returnedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1] objectForKey:@"Summary"]];
[[cell textLabel] setText:[[[returnedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1] objectForKey:@"title"]];

return cell;
}
```

*Another Update

This is what comes up in the debugger when the program crashes. I am to understand from my meanderings through some debugging tutorials that this is the stack trace, if it looks wrong just let me know.

```
#0  0x01be33a7 in ___forwarding___
#1  0x01bbf6c2 in __forwarding_prep_0___
#2  0x00066f13 in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:]
#3  0x00069fe2 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleHeadersAndFootersNow]
#4  0x000727e4 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow]
#5  0x00069953 in -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
#6  0x02f482b0 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
#7  0x02f4806f in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
#8  0x02f478c6 in CA::Context::commit_transaction
#9  0x02f4753a in CA::Transaction::commit
#10 0x02f4f838 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback
#11 0x01bbb252 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers
#12 0x01bba65f in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#13 0x01bb9c48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#14 0x01d6078d in GSEventRunModal
#15 0x01d60852 in GSEventRun
#16 0x00023003 in UIApplicationMain
#17 0x00002a20 in main at main.m:14
```

This is the code i use to get the array:

```
NSURL *XMLURLPath = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.localendar.com.au/events/database_xml.php?day=2010-05-01&endday=2010-05-30"];
returnedEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[localoXMLParser parseXMLDataWithURL:XMLURLPath]];   
[XMLURLPath release];
```

Perhaps this is bad practice? The array is a few levels deep, is it possible that the app is releasing some of the objects within the array somehow?

Comment: Can you post the tableview code?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything wrong with the code, but here is what we can determine from the information you gave.

The error indicates that somewhere the code is failing as a request of length is being sent to a released string (having the stacktrace would help).

The fact that it works with ~5 looks like it may be to do with the dequeueing of cells as you scroll.

When you iterate through the array and access all the members, I presume this is in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and you are logging the text when you scroll? If so, then the array is also fine.

Could it have something to do with the `indexPath.row + 1`, do you have an extra cell that you use to store some other data?

Comment: Hey Liam, thanks for taking the time to answer. The array holds a list of local events, sorted into smaller arrays that hold events on a given date, the first object in each dateArray is an NSString that contains the date, which is used for the title of a tableSection, `indexPath.row + 1` just skips this entry to start pulling data from the NSMutableDictionarys that hold the information for each event. Short answer. It's meant to be there.

Comment: If you get a chance, put up the stacktrace and I'll have a look. It may give more pointers